# Problem in using pyaudio package in Windows environment

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to set up a [amodem](https://github.com/romanz/amodem) package for a student project, my work environment is windows11 and the amodem package uses pyaudio.
I get this error on the initial setup that is related to the pyaudio package, but I don't know why?

I run this command:

```
python -m amodem send --calibrate
```

Result:
`FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libportaudio.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

```
Python  3.9.13
PyAudio 0.2.11
amodem  1.15.4
```